# Seeking Assistance to Enhance Weather Forecast Web App Project

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a project titled "Build-a-Website-using-an-API-with-HTML-JavaScript-and-JSON" available on GitHub at [GitHub Repository Link](https://github.com/zwanski2019/Build-a-Website-using-an-API-with-HTML-JavaScript-and-JSON.git). This project involves creating a simple weather forecast web app using HTML, JavaScript, and JSON with API integration to display real-time weather data for various locations in an easy-to-use and informative manner.

While I have made progress on the project and have established the fundamental structure, including essential files like HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, I am encountering challenges in implementing certain functionalities to enhance user experience and improve the overall performance of the application.

Specifically, I am seeking assistance with the following aspects:

1. Enhancing the visual design and layout of the web app using CSS.
2. Adding interactive features to make the weather data more engaging for users.
3. Optimizing the codebase for better performance and efficiency.

If you have expertise in web development, API integration, or working with weather data, I would greatly appreciate any guidance, suggestions, or code snippets that could help me address these challenges and successfully complete the project.

Thank you in advance for your valuable input and support. Any advice or recommendations will be highly appreciated.

Warm regards,
zwanski

I attempted to implement a new feature in my web application by adding a weather forecast module using an API. I expected the module to display real-time weather data for different locations. However, after integrating the API and updating the code, the weather information did not load correctly,

showing blank results instead. I need assistance in troubleshooting this issue and ensuring the weather data is displayed accurately.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.